# Объединение строк полученных по нескольким критериям

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Задача:** в БД есть некоторая таблица MyTable. Все строки MyTable соответствующие критерию a образуют множество строк A, а все строки соответствующие критерию b образуют множество строк В. Написать запрос, который возвращает объединение множеств A и B, при этом строки выводятся в следующем порядке:

1. Сперва все строки соответствующие только критерию a.
2. Затем все строки соответствующие критерию a и критерию b.
3. Под конец все строки соответствующие только критерию b.
   Критерии a и b не определенны заранее и формируются динамически.

**Что не получается:**

1. сперва я подумал объединить два критерия a и b через оператор OR, но возникли проблемы с сортировкой. Я представляю как отсортировать строки по полю или выражению в котором участвуют несколько полей. Но как выразить сортировку по описанному выше критерию - не могу даже представить.
2. пробовал реализовать описанное поведение через три соответствующих запроса. Но такой подход не эффективен, в особенности, если кол-во критериев больше двух.

Comment: UNION и UNION ALL рассматривали?

Comment: `with --- a, b : (a) union (a exists b) union (b)` Немного схематично, но надеюсь идея читается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если в общем, то как-то так...

```sql
SELECT *,
       {criteria 1 code} AS criteria_1,
       {criteria 2 code} AS criteria_2
FROM table
HAVING (    criteria_1
         OR criteria_2
        )
ORDER BY CASE WHEN criteria_1 AND NOT criteria_2
              THEN 1
              WHEN criteria_1 
              THEN 2
              ELSE 3 
              END
```

`{criteria N code} AS criteria_N` формирует соответствующее количество колонок со значениями 0/1 в зависимости от выполнения критерия для данной записи. Желательно принять меры, чтобы не получать в этих полях NULL. Количество критериев и соответственно вариантов в ORDER BY формируем по своему вкусу и выданному заданию. Иногда можно воcпользоваться и арифметическим выражением (например, для описанного случая вполне подойдёт что-то типа `ORDER BY criteria_1 - criteria_2 DESC`).

Если запрос не допускает использования критериев в HAVING (скажем, требует группировки), или если значения критериев в выходном наборе недопустимы, то в подзапросе формируем значения критериев, а во внешнем запросе выполняем отбор во WHERE, а затем (группируем и) формируем нужное выражение сортировки.

Comment: {criteria N code} AS criteria_N - что это законструкция? Какая-то разновидность оконных функций?

Comment: @Bakuard `{criteria N code}` - это SQL-код вычисления критерия. `AS criteria_N` - это присвоения ему имени в выходном наборе (алиас).